# how to improve .collect() in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any other way to tune pyspark so that .collect()'s performance can be improved?

I'm using `map(lambda row: row.asDict(), x.collect())` which is taking more that 5seconds for 10K records.

Comment: you can convert them into dict before collecting so that it works in distributed way. x.map(lambda row: row.asDict()).collect(). I think this should be faster than doing it after collect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but maybe the
[Apache Arrow](http://arrow.apache.org/) project could help you